# Metrics by filter

Tags: sonarqube, dashboard, code-metrics

With SonarQube 5.4, I try to group metrics informations by filter and display them in an aggregated dashboard. Let me explain:

I have a very big project, not well structured (everything is under a single source folder). Refactoring it is NOT an option. I need to display metrics (files, classes, number of lines, compliance rate, etc.) per "module". A module is identified just by its path on the source folder (module A will be located under src/main/java/com/firm/product/moduleA/, and so on).

What I need is a display like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| Module | File count | Lines count | Defaults | SQALE |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|   A    | 26412      | 1360141     | 436      | B     |
|   B    | 3214       | 1025        | 756121   | D     |
|   C    | 145        | 8037        | 41       | A     |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| Total  | 5451210    | 54121215    | 5421215  | A     |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Where each module is identified by a (measure) filter, and each column is configurable.

Is something available in SonarQube?

Answer (score 1):

You've always been able to get to dashboards for sub-structures in your code. Use the 'Code' menu option ('Components' in older versions of the platform) to see a listing of your project's directories. From there you can get to a package dashboard.

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for. I need to display the metrics for com.firm.product.module.* (for example, the aggregation of com.firm.product.module.persistence, com.firm.product.module.webservices, com.firm.product.module.domain, etc), not the details of each and every subpackage of the given module.